# Why do I get the "you cannot vote to close after retracting your vote" message so often?

Tags: bug

I certainly get this message much, much, much more often than I actually ever retract my vote.

This seems like a bug.

In fact, I think I often find that my 'close' vote isn't there anymore even though I haven't retracted it. When I try to vote to close again, that's the message that I get.

I used to think that it was due to my making an edit to a question after voting to close it.  But now I have an example of a question to which I have made no edits and yet my close vote is gone and I can no longer vote to close.

If this is the intended behavior, I don't know what the desired goal is.

Comment: Can you give one question as an example of where you got the message when you shouldn't have?

Comment: @JJJ [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74647/what-is-the-official-commonly-accepted-definition-of-a-nazi) is the latest where I noticed it.  I noticed it yesterday.  I don't remember when the original vtc date was.  And I don't think I've done anything to retract the vtc.

Comment: Okay, that one you voted to close 20 hours ago, and the question was closed as a result of that and other close votes. It was reopened 11 hours ago. I think you can no longer vote to close it because you already casted a close vote in the previous cycle.

Comment: @JJJ ty for looking into it.  I still think it's a bug to tell users that they took actions they didn't take.  And given how frequent this situation is (close/reopen), it's a bug that happens often.

Comment: Is it a bug that you can't vote to close it or the message is wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question belongs on [Meta.SE], not this specific meta site, since it's about the basic software's behavior.   That said, I'm not sure it's clear enough to be worth moving.

Comment: @JoeW that the message is wrong (because it frequently effects users).

Comment: @Bobson you are probably right.  I don't know.  I wouldn't care if it got migrated.  But I came across it on this site, so I posted it on this site's meta.

Comment: @Bobson although I am not familiar enough with the delineation between the tools available to moderators vs tools available to the site's developers.  In particular, I don't know who populates the strings used as error messages.  Maybe they are specific to sites and maybe they are not.

Comment: Looks like you've encountered [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376335/).

Comment: @wrod It may be wrong but your question lacks the details needed to fully explain what is happening and why it is wrong.

Comment: @Nat ty!.  It's good to know that it is already a known bug.

Comment: @Nat I know there is no need to be formal about the things on this meta site, but if you post your comment as an answer, it should probably be the accepted answer. I am sure this bug, if it doesn't get fixed, will bother others, at some future time, too. In which case, the Q&A might help them see what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per one of the comments to this question, this is a bug [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376335/) on meta.SE site.

Anyone who wants to follow the progress on it should probably do it on the main meta site.

Comment: FWTW, I think the javascript gets borked after a while when keeping the site open (for days). Try closing and reopening the browser process. At least that fixed some related issue for me involving double-clicked delete buttons https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380711/has-the-warning-question-about-retracting-delete-votes-been-intentionally-remo I did not encouter this one you describe (about close votes).

Comment: @Fizz maybe.  i think js may get paused if you switch tabs.  About this bug though, I think the main meta is right.  It's probably just the message you get if you try to vtc after it gets closed/reopened and you were one of the original close votes.  But if you don't remember voting to close, the message looks like a bug every single time.